# Access to SpatiaLite .dumpshp via Python?

Tags: python, spatialite

I'm trying to interact with a SpatiaLite database via Python on my Windows machine.

I've managed to connect to the database and load the SpatiaLite extension, which means that I can pass SQL queries in from my Python code e.g:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
myPath = r"C:\SpatiaLite\test-2.3.sqlite"
conn = sqlite.connect(myPath)
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select load_extension('libspatialite-1.dll')")    
curs.execute("""SELECT name, peoples, AsText(Geometry) from Towns where
                peoples > 350000 order by peoples DESC""")
# Print the selected records
for row in curs:
    print row
```

So far so good. I'd now like to know how to export a table as a shapefile. Using the command prompt in spatialite.exe I can do this using `.dumpshp`, but I can't figure out how to access this command from Python. Any ideas, please?

I was hoping for something like this:

```
curs.execute("select dumpshp('Towns Geometry shape_towns CP1252 POINT')")
```

but perhaps it's more complicated than that?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the command line spatialite_tool and embed it in python with subprocess module.

In command line

```
spatialite_tool -e -shp shape_towns -d test-2.3.sqlite -t Towns -g Geometry -c CP1252 --type POINT
```

In Python

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["spatialite_tool", "-e", "-shp", "shape_towns", "-d", "test-2.3.sqlite", "-t", "Towns", "-g", "Geometry", "-c", "CP1252", "--type", "POINT"])
```

Comment: Thanks! That works really well. Do you know if there's some documentation for spatialite_tools anywhere? I've not had much luck Googling, but it would be interesting to know what else it can do. Thanks again!

Comment: Type in a command line shell spatialite_tool and you will get the options

Comment: Great - thanks Thomas! As you can probably tell, I'm not very good at this yet...

Comment: We all have been beginners so not a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use dumpshp because it is a macro command not a SQL command. I don't know if it is the best solution but you could process row-by-row and export it into shp file.

For example, something like this:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite


myPath = r"D:\testSpatiaLite.sqlite"
conn = sqlite.connect(myPath)
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select load_extension('libspatialite-1.dll')")
curs.execute("""SELECT attribute1, AsText(the_geom) FROM points""")

output = "d:\\points.shp"

out_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'ESRI Shapefile' )
out_ds = out_driver.CreateDataSource(output)
out_srs = None
out_layer = out_ds.CreateLayer("point", out_srs, ogr.wkbPoint)
fd = ogr.FieldDefn('name',ogr.OFTString)
out_layer.CreateField(fd)

for row in curs:
    feature = ogr.Feature(out_layer.GetLayerDefn())
    wkt = row[1]

    point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
    feature.SetGeometry(point)
    feature.SetField('name',row[0])
    out_layer.CreateFeature(feature)
    feature.Destroy()

conn.close()
out_ds.Destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks, Mario, this is a good answer too. I've accepted @ThomasG77's answer as it's simpler, but I'm just starting to use GDAL/OGR and your code will definitely help me in the future. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. :) Yes it is. Its much simpler than mine.